# Access Denied Error: Node.js works, but npm commands fail with 'Access is denied' on Windows

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, cmd.exe

I'm encountering an issue where Node.js seems to be working fine (as evidenced by running node app.js successfully), but npm commands are failing with an "Access is denied" error on my Windows machine. I've tried running commands like npm init, npm -v, npm cache clean -f, and npm u, but each time, I receive the "Access is denied" error. Additionally, attempts to use tools like n stable or sudo npm install -g result in errors or are not recognized.

Here are the details:

Node.js version: v20.10.0
Operating System: Windows
I've already attempted solutions such as running commands with administrator privileges, but the issue persists. Any guidance on resolving this access issue with npm would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgY7W.png)

I have attempted to address the "Access is denied" issue with npm on my Windows machine by taking the following steps:

- Executing npm commands such as npm init, npm -v, npm cache clean -f, and npm u.
- Running the commands with administrator privileges to ensure elevated access.
- Exploring path configurations to ensure that Node.js and npm directories are correctly included.
- Attempting to use external tools like n stable, but encountering errors or command not found issues.
- Trying to use sudo npm install -g, which resulted in a "sudo is not recognized" error.

Comment: Try running As Admin.  Right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Try moving the node.js script file that's executed off of your OneDrive space within the desktop/test folder to a location not located in OneDrive, then launch it from the terminal and see what happens.